# Apex command button onlick to open as a popup in Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, commandbutton, popup

Can you please guide me to open a VF page as a popup on onclick event of apex:commandbutton as window.open is not supported in lightning.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this  creating a lightning component that opens up on click of the command button and then redirect to your vf from oninit handler of that component. you can have that component render as a model dialogue

```
                            let event = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                                event.setParams({
                                    "url":"your vfpage url"
                                });
                                event.fire();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lightning out to open lightning component as pop up modal on init.Also host/container vf page can have javascript methods which you can pass as attribute to lightning component and that method can be invoked from lightning component action .